# Mongo DB get the children information

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Below is the response I am getting when run the below query

```
Order.find().then((find) => {
        res.json(find);
    });

[  
   {  
      "isPrime":false,
      "orderStatus":"Pending",
      "orderTotal":"27.98",
      "orderType":"x",
      "subOrderId":"x",
      "children":[  
         "5bd105dc1b85bc2faca27603",
         "5bd105dd1b85bc2faca2760b",
         "5bd105dd1b85bc2faca27613"
      ],
      "_id":"x",
      "deliveryDate":"x",
      "orderChannel":"xx",
      "orderDate":"xZ",
      "orderLabel":"NA",
      "shipDate":"x",
      "__v":0
   },

]
```

How can I get the information about the children in the same query or may be in a different query?

Comment: Do you want to get back only the children field ?

Comment: no,child data  as a whole i.e once of the child is customer information from a table.Need to get children (id, customer name, address...)

Comment: You have to use $lookup in the aggregation pipeline. Something like `Order.aggregate({$lookup:{from:replace with child collection name, localField:"children", foreignField:"_id", as:"chidren"}})`. Make sure the locaField and foreignField type matches.

Comment: Getting the error MongooseError: Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to `Model.aggregate()`. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip })`, do `Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with the following code
Children 1 to 3 are child documents.Had to make a change in my schema as well

from

```
children:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_ITEMS"} , {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_CUSTOMERS"}, {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_SHIPMENTS"}]
```

to

```
 children1:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_ITEMS"}],
    children2:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_CUSTOMERS"}],
    children3:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:"ONLINE_ORDER_SHIPMENTS"}]



 Order.find({ 'orderStatus': typeFlag}).populate('children1').populate('children2').populate('children3').then((find) => {
        res.json(find);
    });
```